# In SSRS, how do I correctly set up a Drill-Through between reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two reports in BIDS, with a drill-through from the first to the second, passing some parameters along the way. In BIDS, it works awesome. The drill-through report renders, all the parameters do what they're supposed to, and life is great.

But the second I upload the two reports to the reporting server website, the drill-through stops working. The first report shows up correctly, but clicking the drill-through does... nothing. Nothing at all. Not a dang thing.

Report with Drill-through link:
[image: Report with Drill-through link]

Drill-Through Action Properties:
[image: Drill-Through Action Properties]

Drilled-through Data
[image]

---

**Update**

In poking around in the issue a lot more, I discovered the real culprit here wasn't poor navigation, but poor display. In the first screenshot, above (titled "Report with Drill-through link"), the Office column is incorrectly set up. I set the column, and then for the value I had the column as an amalgam of 4 columns and straight text: `[CompanyName] - [CompanyAddress], [CompanyCity], [CompanyState]`. I changed the value to be an expression of `=Fields!CompanyName.Value & " - " & Fields!CompanyAddress.Value & ", " & Fields!CompanyCity.Value & ", " & Fields!CompanyState.Value`, and the drill-through links worked correctly, right away, no other changes needed.

Comment: When you hover over the drillthrough link on the deployed version, is there any link present? If so, what is it?

Comment: No hover-status link shows up. It just basically acts like underlined text with a cursor change to a hand - it Looks like a link, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you deploy the drill through report as well?

Answer (score 0):

Normally what you are doing should work fine. It's possible that there can be issues relating to cross project reports or reports stored in different locations. Instead of selecting your report from the dropdown, I would type in the absolute path to eliminate potential issues:

> The list of report names includes all reports in the current report server project. If the drillthrough report is on the report server but
>   is not in the project, type the name of the report. The report name
>   can contain a relative path from this report or an absolute path to
>   the report on the server. An example of a relative path is
>   …\DrillthroughReport\Store. An example of an absolute path is
>   \SalesReports\DrillthroughReport\Store.
>
> On a report server configured in native mode, specify a drilthrough
>   report name without the file extension .rdl.

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159847(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: So, you're saying that if my link to the report is `"http://myServer/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSales+Reports%2fReportOne&ViewMode=Detail"`, and the drill-through report is `"http://myServer/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSales+Reports%2fReportDetails&ViewMode=Detail"`, I should change the report from looking at "AgentRosterByOffice_<blurredOfficeName>" to ... what? `http://myServer/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx`?ItemPath=%2fSales+Reports%2fReportDetails&ViewMode=Detail" ?

Comment: I tried putting the absolute path in there: "\OfficeReport\AgentRosterByOffice_ReportDetails". I also tried it as a relative path "..\SalesReports\OfficeReport\AgentRosterByOffice_ReportDetails". Problem is: `"The DrillthroughReportName for the text box ‘CompanyName’ is not valid. Item names cannot contain the following reserved characters ;?:@&=+$,\*<>|"."` That's the error when attempting to upload the new version.

Comment: It looks like you have two periods instead of three at the beginning of the relative path, which may be the problem there. But that absolute path - it caused the same error? Because I don't see any of the reserved characters in the name (unless it is the part of the name that you are not showing). Also the absolute path should be longer than the relative, not shorter - it needs to include everything after \ReportServer

Comment: The backslashes cause the error as well. All that said, however, I found the true culprit: The column in the root report was an amalgam of 4 columns and straight text: `[CompanyName] - [CompanyAddress], [CompanyCity], [CompanyState]`. I changed the value to be an expression of `=Fields!CompanyName.Value & " - " & Fields!CompanyAddress.Value & ", " & Fields!CompanyCity.Value & ", " & Fields!CompanyState.Value`, and I'll be damned if the thing didn't start working.

Comment: Nice. If you want to edit your question to explain what the issue turned out to be an how to solve it, it will help others having the same problem.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. :)